# How to draw 100 concentric circles (with four changing attributes) with a for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, geometry, drawing, p5.js

Using `p5.js`, I want to create 100 concentric circles that do the below:

1. Draw initial circle:

   - choose size based on 0.8 x width
   - start at color 1 (based on HSB color mode)
   - start at opacity 0.01 (based on HSB color mode )
   - start at shade 100 (based on HSB color mode)).
2. Draw next circle:

   - size to be 0.98 x previous circle size
   - color to progress by 1
   - opacity to increase by 0.01
   - shade to decrease by 1

I understand how to do this manually by drawing 100 circles with different inputs, but I want to wrap this all up in a for loop. I can get one parameter to change within the for loop but my expertise unfortunately stops there, I am very beginner. If I try hang the other parameters off the same for loop it gets really complex and something seems to break, and I don't quite understand how nested for loops work if that's what I need to do. Thank you for help in advance!

This is what I have tried so far with just 10 circles:

```js
function setup() {
  createCanvas(1000, 1000);
  colorMode(HSB, 360, 100, 100, 100);
}

function draw() {
 
  background(0, 0, 100); // white background
  
  for (let i = width; i >= 0; i = i - width/10) {  
    
    noStroke();
    
    let colour = (i/1000)*360;
    let shade = i/10;
    let opacity = ((i/10)*-1)+100;
    fill(colour, 100, shade, opacity);
    
    let diameter = i;
    circle(width/2, height/2, diameter); 
  } 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: The result looks fairly reasonable. What's the problem with it exactly?

Comment: it lacks the reduction in size of 98% compared to the previously drawn circle.

Comment: All right, so what's preventing you from going ahead and reducing size to 98% on each iteration? Say, `i *= 0.98` rather than `i = i - width/10` which reduces it by 10% of the width per step. Also, the stopping condition would need to be `i >= 1` since `i` will never reach 0.

Comment: The instructions seem pretty clear. For example: "color to progress by 1" almost certainly means `color++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated your code to match what you describe that it should do.

```js
function draw() {
    
  background(0, 0, 100);

  for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    
    noStroke();
    
    let colour = (10*i % 360);
    let shade = 100 - i;
    let opacity = 50 + i;
    fill(colour, 100, shade, opacity);
    
    let diameter = width * Math.pow(0.98, i);
    circle(width/2, height/2, diameter); 
  } 
}
```

- The color is set with `(10*i % 360)`. I tried increasing it by 1, but that didn't do a lot, so I increased it to 10. The `%` operator ensures that it will wrap around `[0, 360]`. As an example `370 % 360 = 10`.
- The shade seems to be between `[0, 100]`, so it starts at fill brightness, and slowly reduces to 0 when it is nearing the center of the circle. This gives a tunnel effect.
- The opacity also seems to be between `[0, 100]`. I have added a starting value of 50 so you can see the effect.
- The diameter is changing based on the iteration of the loop. It uses `Math.pow(0.98, i)` to calculate the coefficient which indicates how small it has gotten.

All in all, this is the result that I've got:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! you have taught me 2 things: % operator - I did not know this existed; Math.pow(), I need to do more looking into this to determine how it works. Not only have you solved my problem, you've created code that allows me to easily change each parameter for different effects. With my limited knowledge, I thought the code for this would need to be much more complex, your solution is very efficient.

Comment: Math.pow(a, b) is the exponent a^b, so if a = 0.98, and b = 5, you get (0.98)(0.98)(0.98)(0.98)(0.98). If you define a = 0.98 outside of the loop, and change a by a *= 0.98, you get the same effect, and that is actually more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

```
function setup() 
{
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(2);
  noFill();
}

function draw() 
{
  background(0);
  translate(width/2,height/2);
  let NUMCIRCLES = 100;
  let startRadius = 100;
  let endRadius = 400;
  for(let i = 0; i < NUMCIRCLES; i++)
  {
    let circleRadius = map(i,0,NUMCIRCLES-1, startRadius, endRadius);
    let color = map(i,0,NUMCIRCLES-1, 20,255);
    let opacity = map(i,0,NUMCIRCLES-1, 100,255);

    stroke(color, opacity);
    ellipse(0,0, circleRadius,circleRadius);
  }
}
```

It would help if you used the map function instead. It's super handy. Also, don't mind that I'm using an ellipse instead of the circle function. I just like thinking in terms of radius.